# Error en programa de sql/pl PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "CREATE"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Este es mi código. El error que da está en el body.

> LINE/COL  ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 22/1      PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "CREATE"
> Errores: comprobar log de compilador

```sql
-- Paquete
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_puntaje_postulante IS
      TYPE puntaje_extrema IS RECORD (
        cod_serv_salud NUMBER(5),
        ptje_zona NUMBER(4)
      );
    
      TYPE puntaje_ranking IS RECORD (
        cod_inst NUMBER(4),
        ptje_ranking NUMBER(4)
      );
    
      zona_extrema puntaje_extrema;
      ranking_inst puntaje_ranking;
    
      FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_ranking_institucion(cod_inst NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
      FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_zona_extrema(cod_serv_salud NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
      
      PROCEDURE asignar_puntaje_postulantes(fecha_proceso DATE, porcentaje_extra_1 NUMBER, porcentaje_extra_2 NUMBER);
    END pkg_puntaje_postulante;
    
    -- Cuerpo del Paquete
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_puntaje_postulante IS
      FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_ranking_institucion(cod_inst NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
        v_puntaje NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        -- Implementación de la función para obtener el puntaje de ranking
        SELECT ptje_ranking INTO v_puntaje
        FROM PTJE_RANKING_INST
        WHERE rango_ranking_ini <= cod_inst AND cod_inst <= rango_ranking_ter;
    
        RETURN v_puntaje;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          raise_application_error(-20002, 'Institución no encontrada en el ranking');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          raise_application_error(-20003, 'Error al obtener puntaje de ranking');
      END obtener_puntaje_ranking_institucion;
    
      FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_zona_extrema(cod_serv_salud NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
        zona_extrema PTJE_ZONA_EXTREMA.zona_extrema%TYPE;
        ptje_zona PTJE_ZONA_EXTREMA.ptje_zona%TYPE;
      BEGIN
        -- Obtener la zona extrema del Servicio de Salud
        SELECT zona_extrema INTO zona_extrema
        FROM SERVICIO_SALUD
        WHERE cod_serv_salud = cod_serv_salud;
    
        -- Si no hay información, registrar un error y retornar 0
        IF zona_extrema IS NULL THEN
          raise_application_error(-20004, 'No se encontró zona extrema');
        END IF;
    
        -- Obtener el puntaje según la zona extrema
        SELECT ptje_zona INTO ptje_zona
        FROM PTJE_ZONA_EXTREMA
        WHERE zona_extrema = zona_extrema;
    
        -- Si no se encuentra la zona, registrar un error y retornar 0
        IF ptje_zona IS NULL THEN
          raise_application_error(-20005, 'Zona extrema no encontrada');
        END IF;
    
        -- Retornar el puntaje
        RETURN ptje_zona;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          raise_application_error(-20006, 'Servicio de Salud no encontrado');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          raise_application_error(-20007, 'Error al obtener puntaje de zona extrema');
      END obtener_puntaje_zona_extrema;
    
      PROCEDURE asignar_puntaje_postulantes(fecha_proceso DATE, porcentaje_extra_1 NUMBER, porcentaje_extra_2 NUMBER) IS
        v_puntaje_annos_exp NUMBER;
        v_puntaje_horas_trabajo NUMBER;
        v_puntaje_zona_extrema NUMBER;
        v_puntaje_ranking_inst NUMBER;
        v_puntaje_extra_1 NUMBER := 0;
        v_puntaje_extra_2 NUMBER := 0;
        v_puntaje_final NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        FOR postulante IN (SELECT * FROM ANTECEDENTES_LABORALES JOIN ANTECEDENTES_PERSONALES USING (numrun)) LOOP
          -- Lógica para calcular el puntaje por años de experiencia
          v_puntaje_annos_exp := ObtenerPuntajeAnnosExperiencia(postulante.fecha_contrato);
    
          -- Lógica para calcular el puntaje por horas de trabajo
          v_puntaje_horas_trabajo := ObtenerPuntajeHorasTrabajo(postulante.numrun);
    
          -- Lógica para calcular el puntaje por trabajar en zona extrema
          v_puntaje_zona_extrema := obtener_puntaje_zona_extrema(postulante.cod_serv_salud);
    
          -- Lógica para calcular el puntaje por ranking de la institución
          v_puntaje_ranking_inst := obtener_puntaje_ranking_institucion(postulante.cod_inst);
    
          -- Puntaje extra 1: Menos de 45 años y más de 30 horas de trabajo
          IF fecha_proceso - postulante.fecha_nacimiento < 45 AND postulante.horas_semanales > 30 THEN
            v_puntaje_extra_1 := (v_puntaje_annos_exp + v_puntaje_horas_trabajo + v_puntaje_zona_extrema + v_puntaje_ranking_inst) * porcentaje_extra_1 / 100;
          END IF;
    
          -- Puntaje extra 2: Más de 25 años de experiencia
          IF postulante.fecha_contrato - postulante.fecha_nacimiento > 25 THEN
            v_puntaje_extra_2 := (v_puntaje_annos_exp + v_puntaje_horas_trabajo + v_puntaje_zona_extrema + v_puntaje_ranking_inst) * porcentaje_extra_2 / 100;
          END IF;
    
          -- Total de puntaje
          v_puntaje_final := ROUND(v_puntaje_annos_exp + v_puntaje_horas_trabajo + v_puntaje_zona_extrema + v_puntaje_ranking_inst + v_puntaje_extra_1 + v_puntaje_extra_2);
    
          -- Insertar en DETALLE_PUNTAJE_POSTULACION
          INSERT INTO DETALLE_PUNTAJE_POSTULACION VALUES (
            postulante.numrun,
            postulante.pnombre || ' ' || NVL(postulante.snombre, '') || ' ' || postulante.apaterno || ' ' || postulante.amaterno,
            v_puntaje_annos_exp,
            v_puntaje_horas_trabajo,
            v_puntaje_zona_extrema,
            v_puntaje_ranking_inst,
            v_puntaje_extra_1,
            v_puntaje_extra_2
          );
    
          -- Insertar en RESULTADO_POSTULACION (Ejemplo: Aprobado si el puntaje final es mayor a cierto umbral)
          INSERT INTO RESULTADO_POSTULACION VALUES (
            postulante.numrun,
            v_puntaje_final,
            CASE
              WHEN v_puntaje_final >= 2000 THEN 'Aprobado'
              ELSE 'Reprobado'
            END
          );
        END LOOP;
    
        COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          INSERT INTO ERROR_PROCESO VALUES (NULL, 'asignar_puntaje_postulantes', SQLERRM);
      END asignar_puntaje_postulantes;
    END pkg_puntaje_postulante;
    /
```

Este es el código completo.

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `IS` por `AS`

Comment: Hola kuma oni, podrías decir si la respuesta dada te fue útil, y en caso de haberlo sido marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a insertar una barra (/) entre la cabecera y el cuerpo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_puntaje_postulante IS
 TYPE puntaje_extrema IS RECORD (
  cod_serv_salud NUMBER(5),
  ptje_zona NUMBER(4)
);

TYPE puntaje_ranking IS RECORD (
  cod_inst NUMBER(4),
  ptje_ranking NUMBER(4)
);

zona_extrema puntaje_extrema;
ranking_inst puntaje_ranking;

FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_ranking_institucion(cod_inst NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
FUNCTION obtener_puntaje_zona_extrema(cod_serv_salud NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;

PROCEDURE asignar_puntaje_postulantes(fecha_proceso DATE, porcentaje_extra_1 NUMBER, porcentaje_extra_2 NUMBER);
END pkg_puntaje_postulante;

/

-- Cuerpo del paquete
```

Hay editores que consideran que se trata del mismo script y lanzan un error cuando detectan el segundo create. Por eso se escribe una barra entre la cabecera y el cuerpo del paquete haciendo que el editor lo vea como dos scripts distintos.